# Can I move an Azure Data Factory Pipeline to Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

My client developed a set o Azure Data Factory Pipeline that are tested and working. They asked me to move them to Azure DevOps. Is this possible? if so, how do i go about this?

Comment: You can connect Azure Data Factory to Azure Devops directly :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery

Answer (score 0):

you can add ADO repos either from the Edit page, or from the Management page in Data Factory, if you haven't done it at the creation of the Data Factory.

Please see below:

[image: Edit page]

[image: Management page]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your Azure Data Factory pipeline is designed to complete. For general purpose to set up an Azure Pipelines release that automates the deployment of a data factory to multiple environments, please refer to [Automate continuous integration - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-automate-azure-pipelines).